# writing yacc grammar for parsing these statements

Tags: yacc

i want to write yacc grammar for parsing statements as follows

```
START  
statement1
statement2  
END  
START
statement3
END
START
statement4
END
```

or

```
START
  statement1
  statement2
  XYZ               (2)
      START
      statement3
      statement4
      XYZ           (1)
      END
  statement5
  XYZ               (3)
END
```

and so on..

there can be any number of such START-END sets.

Each START should have an END.if XYZ appears at (1) then it should be present at (2) and (3) also. however if XYZ is present at (2) and(3) it may or may not be present at (1).that means the innermost START-END set may or may not have XYZ ..
how should i write the grammar for such a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

> Program -> S
>
> S -> S START statements END |  ;
>
> statements  -> statements statement | ;
>
> statement -> NormalStatement | XYZ ;

Now just use a counter to ensure the XYZ existence pattern in your grammar . You can check It in front of `END` in yacc file as you may know how.